# Execute rails runner from within application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How can I execute one-off scripts using `rails runner` from within my application, for example when someone presses a button through a web-interface that will execute a particular task in the background.

My application is structured like

```
myApp
  models
  controllers
  ...
  scripts
     task1.rb
     task2.rb
```

I currently execute them manually from a console window using

```
heroku run rails runner scripts/task1.rb
```

But would like to move to a web interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is non-ideal solution.

```
//  app/workers/runner_task_worker.rb
class RunnerTaskWorker
  def task1
    // call my script method from here.
    // assuming that your script method is included in rails app.
    task1_method   
  end
end
```

So, then call this from web interface `RunnerTaskWorker.new.task1`

NOTE: if you have `worker` in your heroku, please use worker with `sidekiq` , `delayed_job`. The above code will give extra load to heroku `web` server. That's why i said this is non-ideal solution.